# Filter the Property of object using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a scenario where i have to filter the Property of object using LINQ.

Edited: 
I have a Contract
List dtCntList = DTIsland.GenericHelper.ConvertArrayListToGenericList(getList(), true);

Now in the Contract, I have various Property. Each contract have multiple Trips -> Trips have multiple flight.
I have the scenario where i have to select all the flight number in a contract.

Like:
Some Thing Like that

> var allFlightNumber=from Cont in
>   dtCntList[0] select
>   dtCntList[0].trips.dtFlight

or have to select the Outbound trip

> Var outBoundTrip = from cont in
>   dtCntList[0] where cont.trip ==
>   OutBound

But i am not able to perform the LINQ on DTContract Object (dtCntList[0])

Please Help..

Comment: can you elaborate some more? It is not very clear what you want.

Comment: @ Devendra: I have List on a class type like Contract and each contract multiple trips and trips have multiple flightNumber. Now i have to do query on the Object and Get the flight number..But i cant able to query(LINQ) on the objects..

Comment: rather than gradually filling in the details as people ask, show us what the data objects look like (edit out the bits that are irrelevant) and the LINQ query you are trying to use. Then people can tell you exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: DTContract dtCntList = listofContracts_[0];//Array List of Type DTContract 
        
Now i want sumthing like
          
Ex: var lifgtNumber = from Cnt  in dtCntList select Cnt.trips.lostOfFlifht.FlightNumber;

Comment: edit the question to add the code that you have. It is not very readable as a comment. Also, don't forget to add the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the following class heirarchy,

```
class Contract
{
    public List<Trip> TripsList { get; set; }

    public Contract()
    {
        TripsList = new List<Trip>();
    }
}

class Trip
{
    public List<string> FlightNumbers { get; set; }

    public Trip()
    {
        FlightNumbers = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

First the builder method (to construct the object),

```
private Contract Build()
{
    Contract contract = new Contract();

    Trip trip = new Trip();
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("101A");
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("101B");
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("101C");
    contract.TripsList.Add(trip);

    trip = new Trip();
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("102A");
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("102B");
    trip.FlightNumbers.Add("102C");
    contract.TripsList.Add(trip);

    return contract;
}
```

The the LINQ to find whether the flight number exists,

```
Contract c = Build();

if (c.TripsList.Where(trip => trip.FlightNumbers.Contains("103B")).Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Flight number 103B exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda hard to guess what you actually meant.
These are two possible interpretations:

```
var result1 = from item in yourList
              where item.YourProperty=="SomeValue"
              select item;
var result2 = from property in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties()
              where property.Name =="SomeValue"
              select property;
```

Comment: I have List on a class type like Contract and each contract multiple trips and trips have multiple flightNumber. Now i have to do query on the Object and Get the flight number..But i cant able to query(LINQ) on the objects..